# Handling a deep link from the google assistant in Java

Tags: java, android, actions-on-google, app-actions

Looking to handle a deep link from the Google Assistant. As I only have an emulator at the moment I am having trouble testing it (from what I have read it requires a real device). That said, I was wondering if I am handling it the correct way. I am unfamiliar with Kotlin and my code was turning into Spaghetti trying to integrate, so I put this together in my existing launcher activity just to try and get it bootstrapped for now. The manifest and actions.xml were set up like the fitness app tutorial.

Am I doing this correctly?

```
        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            data = this.getIntent().getData();
            if (data != null && data.isHierarchical()) {
                uriData = data.toString();
                containsStart = containsIgnoreCase(uriData,"start");
                containsRun = containsIgnoreCase(uriData,"run");
                if(containsStart && containsRun) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(), RunActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("runStart", true);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                }
            else {
                checkUserAccType();
            }
            //Else, if there is no current user, start the Authentication activity
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few observations and recommendation about your code:

1. Instead of using `containsIgnoreCase` uses `getPath()` and match the path. [See example](https://github.com/actions-on-google/appactions-fitness-kotlin/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/devrel/android/fitactions/FitMainActivity.kt#L144).
2. Also, for the activity parameter use URL query param instead of `containsIgnoreCase`. [See example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60765579/handling-a-deep-link-from-the-google-assistant-in-java)
3. Starting the activity or fragment. I assume `startActivity` and `checkUserAccType` will handle that part. [See example](https://github.com/actions-on-google/appactions-fitness-kotlin/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/devrel/android/fitactions/FitMainActivity.kt#L218).
4. // Else... section should go one line below.
5. Authentication. It looks fine. And it seems you're using Firebase by the `getCurrent` method signature. [See example](https://github.com/firebase/snippets-android/blob/388bc541c0e02461be8947564803f12af286f36d/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/MainActivity.java#L65-L70)